# Ask the user if they want to repeat a python program

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code right now and I need to to ask the user if they want to repeat the program again. I know you need to use the while loop here but I'm stuck.

```
userinput = eval(input("Enter the month as a number "))
results = userinput

if results == 1:
month = "January"
elif results == 2:
month = "February"
elif results == 3:
month = "March"
elif results == 4:
month = "April"
elif results == 5:
month = "May"
elif results == 6:
month = "June"
elif results == 7:
month = "July"
elif results == 8:
month = "August"
elif results == 9:
month = "September"
elif results == 10:
month = "October"
elif results == 11:
month = "November"
elif results == 12:
month = "December"

print("Your birth month of", month)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a million ways to make this more efficient, but here's the basic structure of what you're looking for.

```
endFlag = False
while endFlag == False:        
    # your code here
    ui = input("Would you like to repeat the program again? Y/N")
    if ui == 'N':
        endFlag = True
```